# How does inheritance expose parent implementation to subclasses?

Tags: oop, encapsulation

Just been reading GoF and they state inheritance exposes a subclass to details of its parent's implementation. If the parent class used private member variables and protected functions I dont see how the implementation is being exposed?

Comment: I think they mean the protected functions/members. You should only use the public functions so that you can be agnostic about the protected functions. These functions expose the details of implementation - because if they didn't, they would be "functionality" and hence public.

Comment: Hi Chip, could you reword that please?

Comment: If your subclass is making use of anything that's not a public member of the parent class (which you normally would be, or else why are you inheriting?), then you're depending on details of the parent's implementation to some extent.

Comment: @jjlin, 1) so if i had a private int attribute in my parent called "myvar" and a protected function called "void setmyvar(int val)", if my subclass called setmyvar(5) this is breaking the encapsulation because the subclass is modifying the state of the parent (via "myvar")? 2) I presume abstract classes avoid this because they act like interfaces?

Comment: Modifying state doesn't necessarily break encapsulation; after all, the public interface often lets you modify internal state, but in a controlled way. Here, it sounds like you're controlling access even to your children, which can be useful, but is often overkill.

Comment: [Continuing previous comment, since you can't edit comments after 5 minutes apparently.] My original point is simply that a child class usually has to know something about how its parent works internally, but it's certainly possible to design a parent in such a way that this is minimized. (2) Abstract classes can have implementation too, so they aren't exactly "like interfaces" in the purest sense of the word.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad answer, but here goes, anyway.

When you inherit a class, the Intellisense or Code Completion will let you know which functions and variables (public and protected) you can access or override. That's a partial answer to "how does inheritance expose parent implementation to subclasses?" because you need to know which functions and variables you can access or manipulate.

If you didn't write the parent class, you would need to consult some documentation that will tell you which functions you may override and that function's place (when and from where it's called) in the parent class's implementation. This information lets you know how a parent class is implemented.

If you wrote the parent class yourself, then you already know its behaviors. When you create your child class, you already have in mind how the parent class works, thus you know which variables and functions to access or override.